# Gradle build fails when upgrading to sdk version 23 & support library 23.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I can't upgrade from 22 to 23, gradle keeps throwing this error

```
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar:META-INF/LICENSE])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-lang3-3.4.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [joda-time-2.8.2.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [joda-time-2.8.2.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-io-2.4.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-io-2.4.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [httpcore-4.2.4.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [httpcore-4.2.4.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [libthrift-0.9.2.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [libthrift-0.9.2.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [javax.annotation-4.0-b33.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:META-INF/LICENSE])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar:META-INF/NOTICE])
Warning:can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
```

but in the packaging options block I have

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

Edit: adding debug info from gradle

```
 AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"(com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:191)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:279)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}
```

How do I figure out what the root cause of this is?

Comment: Having same issue @Brian, did you find its solution ?